# Display tweets in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: twitter, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to display latest tweets from some twitter account.

I'm using WebView:

```
  var browser = new WebView
  {
    Source = "https://mobile.twitter.com/microsoft"
  };
```

The following page is displayed:
[image]

Is it possible to remove the header with "Sign up" and "Log in" buttons? If yes, how can I do so?

Answer (score 2):

```
public async void showPage()
{
  WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://mobile.twitter.com/microsoft");
  WebResponse response = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null);

  string html = string.Empty;
  using (var s = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    html = await s.ReadToEndAsync();

  var browser = new WebView();
  var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
  htmlSource.Html = html;
  browser.Source = htmlSource;

  ContentPage cp = new ContentPage();
  cp.Content = browser;
  MainPage = cp;
}
```

With the example code above You can edit the HTML string so that the page meets Your requirements and then display it with WebView. Anyway I strongly recommend other ways of doing it. Especially take a look at [LinqToTwitter](https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter) which is easy to use and cross-platform (works not only with Android and iOS, but also with Windows Phone 8, Windows 10 UWP opposite to Twitter component mentioned by Jason and Sreeraj)

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt to modify the page's CSS to hide that header; I don't know how feasible that is.

Alternately, you could use the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public) or use the [Xamarin Social](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_the_social_framework/) component to get a feed of tweets that you would then display in a custom UI.

Answer (score 0):

Robust and standard method would be to use Twitter API or Xamarin Social Component as already mentioned by Jason. If you want to display in a WebView, I would recommend you to check [Twitter Widgets](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20170071) . I haven't personally tried this, but I believe it should work. Essentially you just sign in with your twitter account and create a widget. It will create some HTML dynamically for you with the values you provide in their settings page. We can copy that and load that HTML into our webview.

This is a method recommended to show feeds in an iframe in webpages. I would still recommend to get feed as JSON in any of the above method and display them.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to keep using a `WebView` I would recommend you follow @float113 example.

Otherwise I would recommend [Tweetinvi](https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi) that will allow you to retrieve the information you want in 2 lines :

```
Auth.SetUserCredentials("CONSUMER_KEY", "CONSUMER_SECRET", "ACCESS_TOKEN", "ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET");
var microsoftTweets = Timeline.GetUserTimeline("microsoft");
```